# Problem with select in async raw query to a Sqlitie DB in Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, xamarin, async-await

Using `ExecuteAsync` works for create, insert, etc., but not for select.
This are the two queries that works: `CREATE TABLE t(x INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, y, z)` and `insert into t(y, z) values(2, 2)`

But select doesn't. This is my code:

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(App.Databaselocation);
var result = await conn.ExecuteAsync("select y from t");
```

And throws this SQLiteException:

> "SQLite.SQLiteException: Row\n  at
>   SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery () [0x000ad] in
>   /Users/vagrant/git/src/SQLite.cs:2334 \n  at
>   SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Execute (System.String query, System.Object[]
>   args) [0x0003a] in /Users/vagrant/git/src/SQLite.cs:673 \n  at
>   SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection+<>c__DisplayClass21_0.b__0
>   () [0x00013] in /Users/vagrant/git/src/SQLiteAsync.cs:222 \n  at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in
>   <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 \n  at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in
>   <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 \n--- End of stack trace from
>   previous location where exception was thrown ---\n  at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 \n  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in
>   <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 \n  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in
>   <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 \n  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in
>   <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 \n  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult ()
>   [0x00000] in :0 \n  at
>   Byou.PoblacionPage+d__1.MoveNext
>   () [0x00044] in
>   C:\Users\sgmon\OneDrive\Projects\Mars\Pob.xaml.cs:41
>   "

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Query/QueryAsync in order to return a result set from a sql select:

```
var result = await conn.QueryAsync<t>("select y from t");
```

Comment: The <t> is the returned class? It can be done without this?. The schema of the app changes, the databases are not always the same... for that reason i need raw queries, or a method to create class in runtime =/

Comment: Dynamic object based result sets are not supported in that framework (you can search the open/closed Issues on github), also on iOS  the dynamic language runtime is not available as System.Reflection.Emit is not a legal action.